# Using Two Regex Strings in SED

Tags: sed

I have this text file where I need to first find a string "BEGINNING" and then find a string "HERE" after the first "BEGINNING" but only once. And there can be any amount of strings in between. This must be done with SED commands so no awk. I know I can simply do /BEGINNING/ to find the first one but I don't know how to put the two together in one SED command.

Comment: You have to use ONLY **sed** command?

Comment: It must be in a .sed file

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$ sed -n '/BEGINNING/,${/HERE/{p;q}}' file
```

may be supported only by GNU sed, not sure.